# How can I append a specific text at the end of each line in a file?

Tags: linux, files, string, text

I have a file called `my_file.txt`. Its content is as follows:

```
7rrmC
7rztC
7s63D
7scfA
7sciA
7seuA
7sh3B
7shgA
7sj9N
7sp5A
7sr2B
7stdC
7sv6A
7sybA
7t2yB
7t30B
7t3bE
7t4rA
7t71A
7t8wD
7tacA
7tbsA
7tfmA
7thhA
7tlx1
7tmvB
7trwA
7txmA
7ughB
7v6dA
7v6iA
7vdvA
7vgmA
7vi7B
7vw1A
7w2vA
7w5vA
7wkkj
7x0dA
7xayA
```

I want to append the string `.ent.gz` at the end of each line.

What Linux command can do that?

Comment: Isn't it easier and faster to google "append text to the end of each line in a file linux" and open one of the hundreds of answers to this question, than to submit a question here? Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the "stream editor" and lets you operate per-line on contents of a file using regular expressions.

`sed 's/$/.ent.gz/' filename.txt` will print each line of the file, replacing the end-of-line regex match `$` with `.ent.gz`.

`sed`'s `-i` flag says "edit the file in place", so if you want to change the contents of the file in-place rather than printing the modifications to standard output, you can run `sed -i 's/$/.ent.gz/' filename.txt`